# Insertar datos de datagrid view C# ASP.NET

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, gridview

Estoy creando un sistema de ventas, al momento de que se registre una venta quiero que se inserten los productos que estan en un datagridview con el ID de la venta

En mi clase VENTA tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
public string Insertar(Venta Venta, List<DetalleVenta> Detalle)
{
    string rpta = "";
    SqlConnection SqlCon = new SqlConnection();
    try
    {
        //Código
        SqlCon.ConnectionString = cadena;
        SqlCon.Open();
        //Establecer la trasacción
        SqlTransaction SqlTra = SqlCon.BeginTransaction();
        //Establecer el Comando
        SqlCommand SqlCmd = new SqlCommand();
        SqlCmd.Connection = SqlCon;
        SqlCmd.Transaction = SqlTra;
        SqlCmd.CommandText = "spinsertar_venta";
        SqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        SqlParameter ParIdventa = new SqlParameter();
        ParIdventa.ParameterName = "@idventa";
        ParIdventa.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int;
        ParIdventa.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
        SqlCmd.Parameters.Add(ParIdventa);

        SqlParameter ParIdEmpleado = new SqlParameter();
        ParIdEmpleado.ParameterName = "@idEmpleado";
        ParIdEmpleado.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int;
        ParIdEmpleado.Value = Venta.Idempleado;
        SqlCmd.Parameters.Add(ParIdEmpleado);

        SqlParameter ParIdCliente = new SqlParameter();
        ParIdCliente.ParameterName = "@idCliente";
        ParIdCliente.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int;
        ParIdCliente.Value = Venta.Idcliente;
        SqlCmd.Parameters.Add(ParIdCliente);

        //Ejecutamos nuestro comando

        rpta = SqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery() == 1 ? "NO se Ingresó el Registro" : "OK";

        if (rpta.Equals("OK"))
        {
            //Obtener el código del ingreso generado
            Idventa = Convert.ToInt32(SqlCmd.Parameters["@idventa"].Value);
            foreach (DetalleVenta det in Detalle)
            {
                det.Idventa = Idventa;
                //Llamar al método insertar de la clase DDetalle_Ingreso
                rpta = det.Insertar(det, ref SqlCon, ref SqlTra);
                if (!rpta.Equals("OK"))
                {
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (!rpta.Equals("OK"))
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

        }


        if (rpta.Equals("OK"))
        {
            SqlTra.Commit();
        }
        else
        {
            SqlTra.Rollback();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        rpta = ex.Message;
    }
    finally
    {
        if (SqlCon.State == ConnectionState.Open) SqlCon.Close();
    }
    return rpta;

}
```

En mi clase INTERMEDIO tengo este codigo:
    //METODO PARA LAS VENTAS

```
public static string InsertarVenta(int idempleado, int idcliente, DataTable dtDetalle)
{
    Venta Obj = new Venta();
    Obj.Idempleado = idempleado;
    Obj.Idcliente = idcliente;

    List<DetalleVenta> detalles = new List<DetalleVenta>();
    foreach (DataRow row in dtDetalle.Rows)
    {
        DetalleVenta detalle = new DetalleVenta();
        detalle.Idproducto = Convert.ToInt32(row["idProducto"].ToString());
        detalle.Cantidad = Convert.ToInt32(row["Cantidad"].ToString());
        detalle.Precio = Convert.ToSingle(row["Precio"].ToString());
        detalles.Add(detalle);
    }
    return Obj.Insertar(Obj, detalles);
}
```

Y en el Boton del formulario tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
    try
    {
        if (!datalistadoDetalle.Rows.Count.Equals(0))
        {
            string rpta = "";
                rpta = Intermedio.InsertarVenta(Convert.ToInt32(txtEmpleado.SelectedValue.ToString()),
                    Convert.ToInt32(txtCliente.SelectedValue.ToString()), dtDetalle);

            error.Text = rpta;
            if (rpta.Equals("OK"))
            {
                ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('Se ha insertado correctamente la venta')", true);

            }
            else
            {
                ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('Ha ocurrido un error al registrar la venta')", true);
            }
            limpiarDetalle();
        }
        else
        {
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('Debe de agregar un producto para vender.')", true);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('Ha ocurrido un error inesperado al registrar la venta')", true);
    }
```

Comment: Hola, ¿Puedes mostrarnos lo que tienes hecho para que tengamos una base desde donde trabajar? Gracias!

Comment: SI Espero y le entiendas

Comment: Hola, el codigo se entiende y tiene sentido, entonces: ¿Cual es el problema que experimentas? Mientras tanto, ¿has intentado usar el debugger para ver donde esta el problema?